# How can I prove the surjectivity of the following function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$F:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2,\\  f(x,y)= ((x^3)-x),y)$

How can I check if this is surjective or not?

Comment: Have you looked up the definition of surjective?

Comment: Try to balance the parentheses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is surjective since $\forall\alpha\in\Bbb R:x^3-x=\alpha$ has at least one real root.

Answer (score 4):

$y$  has no influence to $x^3-x$ and we can choose $y$ any number.

It is enough to show that $r(x)=x^3-x$ is surjective. You can show it in many ways;

$lim_{x\to \infty}r(x)= \infty$ and $lim_{x\to -\infty}=-\infty$ and $r(x)$ continious so for any $a\in \mathbb R$ there exist $x$ such that $x^3-x=a$

Answer (score 1):

You can actually solve $x^3 + x = a$ for $x$.

Write it as $$x ^3 = a - x \tag1$$

Note that $(u-v)^3 = u^3 - 3u^2v + 3uv^2 - v^3$ can be rewritten as
$(u-v)^3 = (u^3 - v^3) - 3uv(u - v)$

Now let $x = u - v$. You get $$x^3 = (u^3 - v^3) - 3uvx \tag2$$

Comparing (1) and (2), we see that we need to solve 
$u^3 - v^3 = a$ and $3uv = 1$.

From $3uv = 1$, we get $v = \dfrac{1}{3u}$. So

\begin{align}
    u^3 - v^3 &= a\\
    u^3 - \dfrac{1}{27u^3} &= a\\
    27u^6 - 1 &= 27au^3 \\
    27u^6 - 27au^3 - 1 &= 0 \\
    27(u^3)^2 - 27a(u^3) - 1 &= 0 \\
    u^3 &= \dfrac{27a \pm \sqrt{729a^2+108}}{54} 
        & \{\text{Note that $729a^2 + 108 > 0$ for all $a$}\} \\
    u^3 &= \dfrac{9a \pm \sqrt{81a^2+12}}{18} \\
    u &= \left( {\dfrac{9a \pm \sqrt{81a^2+12}}{18}} \right)^{1/3}\\
\end{align}

If we let $u = \left( {\dfrac{9a + \sqrt{81a^2+12}}{18}} \right)^{1/3}$, then

\begin{align}
    u^3 - v^3 &= a\\
    v^3 &= u^3 - a \\
    v^3 &= \dfrac{9a + \sqrt{81a^2+12}}{18} - a\\
    v^3 &= \dfrac{-9a + \sqrt{81a^2+12}}{18} \\
    v &= -\left(\dfrac{9a - \sqrt{81a^2+12}}{18} \right)^{1/3} \\
\end{align}

So, a solution is

$$x =
    \left( {\dfrac{9a + \sqrt{81a^2+12}}{18}} \right)^{1/3}
    + \left( \dfrac{9a - \sqrt{81a^2+12}}{18} \right)^{1/3}
\tag3$$

### To verify this solution

Let $x = u-v$, where

$u = \left( {\dfrac{9a + \sqrt{81a^2+12}}{18}} \right)^{1/3}$
and 
$v = -\left( {\dfrac{9a - \sqrt{81a^2+12}}{18}} \right)^{1/3}$

Note that
\begin{align}
    uv
    &=  -\left( {\dfrac{9a + \sqrt{81a^2+12}}{18}} \right)^{1/3}
        \left( {\dfrac{9a - \sqrt{81a^2+12}}{18}} \right)^{1/3} \\
    &=  -\left[
            \left( {\dfrac{9a + \sqrt{81a^2+12}}{18}} \right)
            \left( {\dfrac{9a - \sqrt{81a^2+12}}{18}} \right)
        \right]^{1/3} \\
    &= -\left( \dfrac{81a^2 - (81a^2+12)}{324} \right)^{1/3}\\
    &= -\left(-\dfrac{12}{324} \right)^{1/3}\\
    &= \dfrac 13
\end{align}

and
$u^3 - v^3 =
     \left( {\dfrac{9a + \sqrt{81a^2+12}}{18}} \right) +
     \left( {\dfrac{9a - \sqrt{81a^2+12}}{18}} \right)
     = a$

So
\begin{align}
    x^3 + x
    &= (u-v)^3 + (u-v)\\
    &= (u^3 - 3u^2v + 3uv^2 - v^3) + (u-v)\\
    &= (u^3 - v^3) -3uv(u-v) + (u-v) \\
    &= a - (u-v) + (u-v) \\
    &= a
\end{align}

Comment: That's the only complete solution among all the answers. +1